# Laravel database structure changing

Tags: laravel

I have tables and my tables primary keys are `increments` `$table->increments('id');` based, while laravel 5.8 default primary keys are `bigIncrements`.

#### Question

**I want to know is there any way to change my `increments` to `bigIncrements` automatically but providing new migration or not?**

#### Sample

When we have existing table and we need add or remove column from that table we simply create new migration and tell it to add or remove `x` column.

Comment: It's tricky. If `$user->id` is changed to bigIncrements, you will have to do the same to `$comment->user_id`. If you make use of foreign key constraints, it won't execute at all (sql fail), so you'll have to run `Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();` first. My suggestion is: if it's not really necessary, let it be. You can populate a table up to 4,294,967,295 records on `increments()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please Don't be upgrade laravel 5.7 or lower version to 5.8, because, if you are doing these, you need to create manually migration for alter primary keys increments to bigIncrements, also foreign keys integer to bigInteger, best way please don't upgrade laravel version, there are many change in laravel 5.8.

Read more on below link:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade

[image]

Comment: I've done that. From 5.8 (originally written in 5.1, upgraded one by one) without any DB changes. I had no issues, not on test nor production. It is true that a fresh project in 5.8 will create bigIncrements but it won't affect existing projects.

Comment: no i didn't upgrade my app is 5.8 but the thing is we used generator for creating our tables and generator used `increments` instead of `bigIncrements` same goes for `integer` columns as you mentioned, so all i need now is to change this table settings.